# JMeter - Count requests with responses below defined time

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

Can you recommend plugin or report for Jmeter 4.0 which count number of requests with responses lower than < define time (eg, 200ms, 500ms, etc.)

I would like get answer on below question:

1. How many requests per sec can be sent that response time of 90% responses is lower than 200ms
2. How many responses is below 200ms from Total
3. % of responses to the response below 200 ms from Total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing plugin which implements your requirement, however you can achieve this using [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener)

1. Add JSR223 Listener to your Test Plan
2. Put the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (prev.getTime() < 200) {
       prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + " < 200")
   }
   ```
3. That's it, if your Sampler response time will be below 200 the JSR223 Listener will amend its label and add `< 200` postfix to it.
4. You can view total number of samplers with response time below 200 ms and [90% percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) using "normal" [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener

   [image: JMeter Aggregate Report Listener]

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Duration Assertion". It will fail all the requests which take more than the expected time and with the "View Result Tree" or "Simple Data writer" listener you can get all the required data and count from the csv/jtl file generated by them.

[image]

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you will need absolute numbers, I would recommend the Response Times Percentiles listener (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimePercentiles/)

This listener will paint a graph of response times and this will clearly show in percentiles below any response time within the range